# Detect numeric type of result

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need to get my division function working in python, how can i get it so that it asks a division question, only if the result is an integer, and there is no rounding done?
my division function is as follows:

```
def division():
    global Question
    global correct
    global incorrect
    Question = Question + 1
    print ("________________________________________________________________________________")
    print ("Ok Then, This is question:", Question,)
    number = (random.randint (12,24) * level)
    second_number = (random.randint(2,12)* level)
    print (number,"/",second_number)
    answer = number//second_number
    guess = input ()
    if guess == str (answer):
        print('Correct!')
        correct = correct + 1
    elif guess != str(answer):
        print("Sorry, but that's wrong!The answer was:", answer, "Onto the next question then!")
        incorrect = incorrect +1
```

right now, i am getting things like 0/4 ad 17/9, to name a few, so how do i get it to only ask questions that are actually do able without rounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to get your program to only ask questions that result in integer answers you're thinking about it backwards. Instead it would be much easier to write code that given a random integer, creates a fraction out of it. Otherwise you would have to have multiple test cases and loops to ensure that your question reduces to an integer.

Something like:

1) Randomly select an integer result (Lets say "base")

2) Multiply "base" by another random integer (Lets say "multiple")

3) Then give the question as numerator = "base" * "multiple" and denominator = "multiple"

You could do this very efficiently and quickly in your code, I would provide you it, but I feel it's more helpful to provide the algorithm rather than telling you how to do it.